# java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java

I have an application using AppFuse and mysql database

The problem is sometime the following exception is thrown :

```
Jan 27, 2011 4:54:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint acceptSocket
SEVERE: Endpoint ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,port=0,localport=8080] ignored exception: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.accept(PlainSocketImpl.java:384)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(ServerSocket.java:453)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(ServerSocket.java:421)
    at  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.DefaultServerSocketFactory.acceptSocket(DefaultServerSocketFactory.java:60)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.acceptSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:368)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.TcpWorkerThread.runIt(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:549)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:683)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Jan 27, 2011 4:54:56 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint acceptSocket.

Please could any one tell me the main reason for that exception? And if that exception can lead tomcat to be shutdown ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: http://amitbhayani.blogspot.com/2010/01/javanetsocketexception-too-many-open.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Nishant for your help. But if this exception can lead tomcat to be shutdown or not ??

Answer (score 1):

are you performing a bunch of sql statements against your db in a tight loop?

If so, make sure you do stmt.close() on each one.

Comment: Thanks Joe , But is there an automated tool that can find the unclosed statements? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Not sure about that. Hopefully you can narrow the behavior to some region of code. Also, if your app separates data access classes into a central place, you can look there to see if it is releasing the resources.